# NextJs confusing library imported by using next/dynamic with component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am building my first NextJs app for production, I'm a newbie so this is kind of an experiment. In my app I am using `PeerJs` for real-time communication, however when I import `PeerJs` the normal way I get below error,

This error occured because on the Server-Side Render the navigator is not present.

```
node_modules\peerjs\dist\bundler.mjs (108:0) @ new eval
 ⨯ ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
```

I also tried importing the library dynamically using below mentioned ways but then `NextJs` treats the library as a JSX component.

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
const peerjs = dynamic(() => import('peerjs'), { ssr: false });
```

/

```
const { default: Peer } = await import('peerjs')
```

What am I doing wrong, if anyone knows please tell :)

Comment: Can you share the usage of `peerjs` ? Where do you use `navigator` ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the nextjs app router. In the app router, every component is a server component by default.

peerjs needs navigator to work. from your error, it is undefined. The navigator object is a property of the window object, so it is available on the client side only. so you need to use this on the client-side component using "use client" directive at the top of component.

Comment: Yes I have written "use client" as I am using useEffect() but the problem doesn't goes away

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that PeerJS is running only on the client, you can import it in the `useEffect` hook:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    import("peerjs").then(({ default: Peer }) => {
        const peer = new Peer();
        ...
    });
}, []);
```